# Some entries delete_option doesn't work

Tags: options

I use delete_option to delete all my database options when my plugin is uninstall or when users click a button: Remove all settings and cache

```
<form action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-post.php'); ?>" method="post">
        <h2>Remove all settings, widget(s) and cache (including all WP transients related to this plugin)</h2>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="advanza_direct_plugin_delete_and_cleanup">
        <?php submit_button( 'Remove all settings and cache', 'delete', '', false ); ?>
</form>
```

This is where I use delete_option

```
function advanza_direct_plugin_delete_and_cleanup() {

// Deleting plugin options: terms of service and privacy policy
delete_option('advanza_direct_terms_of_service');
delete_option('advanza_direct_privacy_policy');

// Deleting plugin options: form settings
delete_option('advanza_direct_form_to');
delete_option('advanza_direct_form_subject');

// Deleting everything else
delete_option('external_updates-advanza_direct_plugin_updater'); // Resets updater
delete_option('widget_advanza_direct_form'); // Remove all Advanza Direct form widget(s)

delete_transient( 'advanza_direct_terms_of_service' );
delete_transient( 'advanza_direct_privacy_policy' );

// at the end redirect to target page
exit( wp_redirect( admin_url( 'admin.php?page=advanza-direct-plugin-settings' ) ) );

}
add_action( 'admin_post_advanza_direct_plugin_delete_and_cleanup', 'advanza_direct_plugin_delete_and_cleanup' );
```

The only options not deleted are:

- widget_advanza_direct_form
- external_updates-advanza_direct_plugin_updater

[image: phpmyadmin]

Is this normal behavior? Or do I need to do this in an other way?

Comment: You could go to the [source code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.8/src/wp-includes/option.php#L555) and dump ie. `$results` to find out whats going on.

Comment: Today I'm going to check what's happening.